# Android 9 : How to get Audio in Background from Call made by phone in my app

Tags: android

I have heard a lot about blocking the call recording in android 9. I want to understand is it possible to get audio stream in a background service. Every time a user make a Call. If anyone can help me here what are approach to achieve this like giving notification/asking permission to user for this or building a system app or a plugin or a service. For me Audio stream are required to convert it into speech to text.

i got reference from android documentation for [incallService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService),[building a calling App](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged)  and [implementing real time text](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/rtt). I have no idea how to connect these three together to get Audio Stream in background service

Comment: you can rafer this [Background services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service)